# Angular unit testing .subscribe()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, subscribe

Can't unit test subscribe(). No result returned for portfolioType

component.ts

```
 getPortfolioType() {
    this.dataService.getPortfolioTypeList()
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.portfolioType = response.payload.portfolioList;
      })
  }
```

data.service.ts

```
public getPortfolioTypeList(): any {
    return this.http.getData('/portfolio/portfolioTypeList');
  }
```

http.service.ts

```
getData(action: any, data: any = {}): any {
    const url = environment.API_URL + action;
    const params = Object.keys(data);
    let httpParams = new HttpParams();

    if (params.length) {
      params.forEach((key: string) => {
        httpParams = httpParams.append(key, data[key]);
      });
    }

    return this.http.get(url, {params: httpParams});
  }
```

Case for service (pass)

```
it('should pass service getPortfolioTypeList', () => {
    const test = {
      "test": "test"
    }
    let result: any;
    dataService.getPortfolioTypeList().subscribe(t => {
      result = t;
    });
    const req = httpMock.expectOne({
      method: "GET",
      url: environment.API_URL + '/portfolio/portfolioTypeList'
    });

    req.flush([test]);

    expect(result[0]).toEqual(test);
  });
```

Added a simple function call

```
it('Get data from getPortfolioType', () => {
    component.getPortfolioType();
    console.log(component.portfolioType); // <<< is empty
  });
```

Why component.portfolioType is empty?

Comment: The `getPortfolioType()` function makes an HTTP call which is asynchronous. You are trying to display the value before the "server" has responded.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Even if set async - the response comes empty. What is the correct way to write in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this case

Add a Mock for DataService

```
class MockDataService {
  getPortfolioTypeList(): Observable<any> {
    return of(
      {
        "someKey": "someData"
      }
    )
  }
}
```

And test case

```
it('Check getPortfolioType', fakeAsync(() => {
    const testResponse = {
      payload: {
        portfolioList: [
          {
            "someKey": "someData1",
          }
        ]
      }
    };

    spyOn(dataService, 'getPortfolioTypeList').and.returnValue(of(testResponse));
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.getPortfolioType();
    tick();
    flush();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.portfolioType).toBe(testResponse.payload.portfolioList);
  }));
```

[Code coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNYIh.png)